# Can't install ImGui in a GLFW project in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glfw, imgui

I have a GLFW project in Visual Studio and I want to add ImGui to it. I followed a tutorial to install it and I simply picked up some file and added to the project but it gives me a lot of error (+200). The main error is:

> #error
>
> "Cannot detect OpenGL loader!"

The tutorial that I followed is this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVaQuNXueFw&ab_channel=TheCherno.

I tried to find some guides but I couldn't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any OpenGL loader library such as GLEW or GLAD? Without an OpenGL loader ImGui is not gonna work.
If you don't have any, download [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLAD](https://glad.dav1d.de/).

Here is a video about how to setup

- GLEW: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2E3yO0J7TM
- GLAD: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFyHIc89z1g